# Sending text between Java Server and Node.js client

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, sockets

I have a premade Java server that i used for a different project. I created a simple Node.js client that connect to the server (that works fine) but the problem i'm facing is when i try to send messages between them.
I'm using DataOutputStream.writeUTF and DataInputStream.readUTF for reading and sending messages on the server and when I send for example "Test" to the client it outputs Test but if i send a message from client nothing happens. (The server receives message if i send it from a Java client)

I tried encoding and decoding into UTF-8 on the Node.js client

The Client:

```js
const net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(port, ip, function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write("Hey Server");
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: Well, nobody can debug your server without your server source code. Anyway, writeUTF and readUTF in Java adhere to a specific  but well-documented proprietary protocol that the node.js net module knows nothing about.

Comment: Ahh i though it must be something like that... Ty. I ended up just changing all the readUTF and writeUTF with read and write